# How to get access permissions (octal) for a file on mac os?

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions

How can I get the octal permissions for a file?

```
/tmp$ ls -al myfile 
-rw-r--r--  1 wim  wheel     0B Oct 20 22:31 myfile
/tmp$ the_command myfile
644
```

Tried a suggestion I've found in other answers on here, and it didn't work:

```
/tmp$ stat -c "%a %n" myfile 
stat: illegal option -- c
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New info obtained (and shorter): `stat -f '%A' <filename>`
You can also use `*` for all files and folder. If you need them in a nicer format you can use 
`stat -f '%A %N' <filename>` which will show the octal permission and filename.

Credit: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/152003 - check the first comment of this answer
 
http://geeklog.adamwilson.info/article/58/getting-file-permissions-in-octal-on-OS-X

---

Edited to add:
To check your result, try running `stat -f "%Sp %OLp" <filename>` which will give you the --rwxrwxrwx style + the Octal version